# How do I generate a list of n unique random numbers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a randomly generated array of x numbers with no duplicates. I am choosing numbers, one at a time, then comparing each new number to the numbers already in the array.

Here is my code. At the end I should have an array of seven numbers, none that match, but sometimes I get a nil:

```
array = [] #DEFINES THE ARRAY

array[0] = rand(10)  #THIS CHOOSES FIRST NUMBER (FN) AND PUTS IT IN THE FIRST ARRAY SPOT
p "fn = #{array[0]}"

for i in 1..6  #START OF FOR LOOP TO GET 6 NUMBERS IN THE ARRAY - WHY 6?  THE FIRST NUMBER THAT POPPED IN MY HEAD

  p "Iteration #{i} -------------------------"  # THIS IS JUST SO I KNOW WHERE I AM IN THE LOOPS

  @x = rand(10)  #THIS CHOOSES THE NEXT NUMBER AND ALL NUMBERS AFTER

  array.each do |uc|  # THIS IS THE LOOP THAT COMPARES ALL NUMBERS

    @type = @x == uc ? "yes" : "no"  #DOES THE CHOSEN NUMBER EQUAL ANY NUMBER IN THE ARRAY

    p "does #{uc} = #{@x}? #{@type}"
    if @type == "yes"  # IF THE COMPARE IS TRUE, I DON'T WANT ANYTHING DONE.  IT WILL CYCLE THRU AND GET A NEW NUMBER

      i = 1 
      p "YES #{@x} = #{uc}"
      break
    end  #END OF IF YES
  end  #END OF ARRAY EACH

  if @type == "no"  #IF NO, PUT NEXT NUMBER (@X) INTO THE NEXT ARRAY SPOT.

    p "in last if type= #{@type}"  #THESE STATEMENTS JUST PRINT OUT THE DIFFERENT VARIABLES SO I KNOW I AM GETTING WHAT I EXPECT

    p "in last if x = #{@x}"
    p "in last if i = #{i}"
    @x = array[i]  #THIS "SHOULD" FILL THE NEXT ARRAY SPOT - BUT DOESN'T SEEM TO

    p "#{array[i]} is in the array"  #THIS PRINT OUT IS BLANK - STATEMENT ABOVE DID NOT WORK.

    p array[i]
  end  #END OF IF NO

end  #END OF FOR LOOP

p array #PRINTS OUT THE CONTENTS OF THE ARRAY
```

I know there are probably quicker and easier ways to do this, but I am starting out with what I know, and building up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand what you really want, but this simple one-liner generates an array of ten elements (from 1 to 10) with a random order. Tweak it to meet your needs:

```
(1..10).to_a.shuffle
#=> [4, 10, 1, 7, 3, 5, 8, 2, 9, 6]
```

Comment: Actually it had to be `(0...10).to_a.shuffle.take(7)`.

Comment: Why did u append @steenslag answer?

Comment: @Nakilon, I hadn't understood that the OP wanted only 7 elements (I am not sure yet, he didn't give feedback), your comment make my realize this. So I just completed it.

Comment: @tokland, but everyone can *realize* the best solution – why to accumulate answers, that were already posted by another people?

Answer (score 9):

The [sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample) method does what you want:

```
(1..10).to_a.sample(7) #=> [2, 9, 1, 6, 8, 10, 4]
```

Comment: That could return duplicates I believe.

Comment: @kamoroso94 from the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-sample): "(...) in order to ensure that an element doesn’t repeat itself unless the array already contained duplicate elements."

Comment: thanks for the correction!  I'm still learning Ruby, so I must have misremembered.

Answer (score 4):

1. Why do you put empty lines everywhere? They don't make your code more readable.
2. If you used `@` not because you are writing classes, but just to fix scope problems, you may try either use `$` instead or even better define `type` variable outside the nested loop (before `array.each do |uc|`).
3. And the main thing. Ruby's loops are more highlevel, than in, for example, C. And you can't directly change the `i` value. So you should use keyword `redo` to repeat the iteration. http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html
4. You may use `puts` instead of `p` to get rid of `""`, but it may need `STDOUT.sync = true` fix under Windows.
5. Also you need `array[i] = x` instead of `x = array[i]`. If you aren't experienced in programming, I would recommend to start with C/C++.

So here is your program. Not refactored yet, but fixed.

```
array = []
array[0] = rand 10
puts "fn = #{array[0]}"
for i in 1..6
  puts "Iteration #{i} -------------------------"
  x = rand 10
  array.each do |uc|
    $type = x == uc ? "yes" : "no"
    puts "does #{uc} = #{x}? #{$type}"
    if $type == "yes"
      puts "YES #{x} = #{uc}"
      break
    end
  end
  if $type == "no"
    puts "in last if type= #{$type}"
    puts "in last if x = #{x}"
    puts "in last if i = #{i}"
    array[i] = x
    puts "#{array[i]} is in the array"
    p array[i]
  else
    redo
  end
end
p array
```

#### Now refactoring:

You need to know, that Ruby arrays have a method [`#include?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F), which you may use instead of loop. We will lose debugging ability a bit, but it makes program more pretty, and now we don't need to make `type` variable global.

```
array = []
array[0] = rand 10
puts "fn = #{array[0]}"
for i in 1..6
  puts "Iteration #{i} -------------------------"
  x = rand 10
  type = array.include?(x) ? "yes" : "no"
  puts "does array include #{x}? #{type}"
  if type == "no"
    puts "in last if type=#{type}, x=#{x}, i=#{i}"
    array[i] = x
    puts "#{array[i]} is in the array"
  else
    redo
  end
end
p array
```

Then get rid of `"yes"` and `"no"`, and use native Ruby `true` and `false`. And you may add [`tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) to any object for debugging purposes - this universal method returns the object itself after execution, so you will be able to comment it later via putting `#` before `.tap` (when you don't need debug output) without breaking the program.

```
array = []
array[0] = rand 10
puts "fn = #{array[0]}"
for i in 1..6
  puts "Iteration #{i} -------------------------"
  x = rand 10
  if (type = array.include? x).tap{ puts "does array include #{x}? #{type : "yes" : "no"}" }
    redo
  else
    puts "in last if type=#{type}, x=#{x}, i=#{i}"
    array[i] = x
    puts "#{array[i]} is in the array"
  end
end
p array
```

But actually you print the `type` the second time only when it is `false`, so don't do it. Also we don't need `else` in this case, because `redo` will throw us away from this iteration. And actually we can start from iteration 0 and then change `for` to `times`. But we will lose the `puts "fn="` (I don't know, whether you really need it).

```
array = []
7.times do |i|
  puts "Iteration #{i} -------------------------"
  x = rand 10
  redo if array.include?(x).tap{ |type| puts "does array include #{x}? #{type ? "yes" : "no"}" }
  puts "x=#{x}, i=#{i}"
  array[i] = x
  puts "#{array[i]} is in the array"
end
p array
```

Comment: Outstanding.  Thank you very much for showing me how my code was wrong in the first place, and then going farther by simplifying it in easy to understand steps.  I learned much, and I greatly appreciate it.